# Issue on Resetting Contact Form by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

Can you please take a look at <kbd>[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/t8nj2pm5/1/)</kbd> and let me know why I am not able to Reset my Form?

Here is the code I am using for:

```
$(function () {
    $("#reset").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$('#theForm')[0].reset();
        $('#theForm').trigger("reset");
    });
});
```

As you can see I already tried both `$('#theForm')[0].reset();` and `$('#theForm').trigger("reset");` but neither is working can you please also let me know how I can do the reset on submit as well? thanks

Comment: have you tried $('#theForm').reset();

Comment: Hi Rice Junkie, thanks for reply I just tried your comment but still not working!

Comment: Might be useful if you add your HTML markup as well

Comment: but they are at above demo jsfiddle!

Comment: I see. I think you need a function that manually resets all the fields on click. for example sets the val() of input to "" and so on

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a real reset button?
`<input type="reset" >`

Comment: You left the jquery code.  You dont need it.  See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/t8nj2pm5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Rename your reset button's ID to "resetbtn" and it works!

Now, what's going on... well if you debug the javascript code you will notice that $('#theForm')[0].reset refers to the button, not the reset function. It appears that by giving a field within your form the ID 'reset' you have unwittingly overwritten the reset function.

I'm sure someone with a little more experience with Javascript will tell you what's really happening here, and if there are any better workarounds.

**Update** Check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset

> If a form control (such as a reset button) has a name or id of reset it will mask the form's reset method. It does not reset other attributes in the input, such as disabled.